# На этой странице обнаружена циклическая переадресация и не только

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Приветствую всех пользователей Хэшкода. У меня вопрос - я делал тестирование браузерной игры и получил такую ошибку, когда захожу на страницу управления альянсом (ошибка возникла после того как любой игрок покидает альянс):

[img](http://s5.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2014/01/e545cb347d61055845e44e2990fa4676.png)

И еще один глюк произошел - при отправке войск на атаку, они должны пройти некоторое расстояние, когда таймер доходит до нуля, произошел глюк, происходит циклическое обновление страницы: (раньше такого глюка никогда не было)

[img](http://s5.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/thumbs/2014/01/de268de531984a11da51520c0169f66a.png)

Я сейчас на работе и пока не могу выложить код. Есть какие-нибудь предположения почему так происходит и как бороться с этими ошибками?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> какие-нибудь предположения почему так происходит

Страница переадресуется сама на себя

> как бороться с этими ошибками

Не переадресовывать на ту же страницу, хотя-бы после первой переадресации (поставить условия).

Comment: Это я понимаю, но когда тестировали игру перед запуском такого не было, поэтому и решил спросил...

Comment: @eprivalov1 ну, думаю лучше у тестеров спрашивать. Возможно они просто сквозь пальцы тестировали ) Либо вы нашли сверх баговину, которая только при этих данных зацикливается.

Просто без кода можно делать такие выводы )